# How to get number of activity runs in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I see total cost of ADF Activities from Cost Analysis.

But where I can see how many time activities have run in last month?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programatically Get ADF pipeline consumption report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68017384/programatically-get-adf-pipeline-consumption-report)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created Azure data factory and created pipeline and implemented copy data activity.
Image for reference:

[image]

I want to show the activity runs of pipeline. For that I followed below steps:

Go to Monitor ->pipelineType(Triggered/debug) ->Click on pipline which we want to see the activity runs as mentioned below

[image]

When click on the pipeline I got activity runs of pipeline as below

[image]

if we want to get consumption of pipeline, click on consumption will get as below

[image]

[image]

How many days we want to search we can select as mentioned below:

[image]

In this way we can get the activity runs of azure data factory.